# How to render a form without a class in other service?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to generate a class-less form inside my service.

The way I do it is:

```
class StepSummary implements StepInterface 
{
    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getVariables()
    {
        $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('text')
            ->add('accept')
            ->getForm();

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
}
```

In the [API](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html#method_createBuilder), I've found that I need to pass a form type to the `FormBuilder` - I didn't find any reference to that, so I've put imaginary `text` string. Now it renders the form but this way:

```
<input type="text" id="text" name="text" required="required" />
```

Obviously there is no reference to the `accept` field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller's `createForm()` method was quite helpful here:

```
    public function createFormBuilder($data = null, array $options = array())
    {
        return $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $data, $options);
    }
```

So the solution is:

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form')
            ->add('accept')
            ->getForm();
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the chapter in the Symfony2 documentation called [Using a Form without a Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class).

Basically, you have to use `createFormBuilder` and instead of a string or an object you just pass an array with the default values.

From the documentation mentioned before:

```
// make sure you've imported the Request namespace above the class
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request
// ...

public function contactAction(Request $request)
{
    $defaultData = array('message' => 'Type your message here');
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('message', 'textarea')
        ->getForm();

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bind($request);

            // data is an array with "name", "email", and "message" keys
            $data = $form->getData();
        }

    // ... render the form
}
```

Comment: I do know this code. `createFormBuilder()` is a controller method - I can't inject controller to the service.

Comment: It did however help to found the solution. :)

Comment: I did not read that you want to do this in a service. But the important part is that, unlike states in the API documentation, you can also pass an array to the `createBuilder` method.

Comment: I did try that and unfortunatelly, no, you can't. At least in 2.0.17.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t want to tie your form to any particular object, you don´t need to pass any object to the builder, you can do:

```
    $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder()
        ->add('accept')
        ->getForm();
```

If you want to set some defaults for the form, you can tie the form to an array. For example:

```
    $data['accept'] = 'default accept';

    $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder($data)
        ->add('accept')
        ->getForm();
```

Comment: Both examples will throw you an `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactory::createBuilder() (...)` error.

Comment: EDIT: The second one will actually throw: `Expected argument of type "string or Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface", "array" given`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I thought you were using CreateFormBuilder instead of CreateBuilder. Your answer is the right one