# Symfony2 First form entity overriding second

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a contact form on a page that has a name field, email field and textarea field. It is made in the most simple way...

```
$contactEntity = new ContactEntity();
$builder-> $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $kontaktEntity, array();
$builder->add() ... fields added
```

Then, in the administrative area, I have a search form that searches for the reacivied messages with name and email fields. I create that form with a different entity with the fields `name` and `email` that are one of half a dozen other fields in ContactEntity.

The problem is that the search form is rendered in twig as if it was kontakt form.

To clarify, `SearchEntity` has fields `name` and `email`. `ContactEntity` also has the same fields but with addition of some other fields. When the search form is rendered in twig, it shows the `name` and `email` fields as if it were part of `ContactEntity`.

Also, twig customization doesn't work. I cannot change label text values, I cannot remove HTML5 validation, and can't do anything beacuse nothing works. I tried renaming the fields in the search entity but it doesn't work.

Twig rendering is made on diffrenet twig scripts and is normal and basic in both both forms. This is on a search form. Changing label taxt to `Name` doesn't work. The submit value, on the other hand, is correctly rendered.

```
{{ form_start(form, {attr: {'no-validate' : 'novalidate'}}) }}
        <div class="search-rom">
            {{ form_label(form.name, 'Name') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
        </div>

        <div class="search-rom">
            {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email') }}
            {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
            {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
        </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

To summarize, twig is rendering two of the fields of an entity that the built form has nothing to do with.

**EDIT**

I've just tested if `SearchEntity` is filled when form is submitted and it is, with the correct values. I really don't know what is going on here.

**EDIT 2**

This is a code fragment from the messageAction() method in the controller.

```
$searchEntity = new SearchEntity();
$builder = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder('form', $searchEntity, array());
$builder->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'text')
        ->getForm();
```

Then form is rendered in the response with `$form->createView()`

Comment: Show us more code. Include how you're rendering the form with twig.

Comment: Show us the action that renders that twig file

Comment: What do you mean, the action? I send a response with the $form->createView(). Nothing else.

Comment: You need to show code in order for us to help you. 3 lines is not enough. We aren't psychics. An action is a function in your controller.

Comment: It's pretty large beacuse it's doing a lot of other stuff so shoing it is not productive, but I'll show a fragment that creates a form.

Comment: Thats fine, just need the relevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to pass the builder an entity. In other examples you can just create the entity after getting the data.

[How to render a form without a class in other service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385888/how-to-render-a-form-without-a-class-in-other-service)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem is. It's translations.

I'm Croatian and site I'm building has two languages, english and croatian with english as the default locale. Translation is done in various ways, but the translation of forms and all that comes with forms is done via messages.en.php.

For translations, i choose array type. `message.en.php` looks like this...

```
... Some data to translate ...

'Ime' : 'Personal name or bussiness'
'Email' : 'Email address

... Some other data to translate
```

So, when twig tried to render this...

```
form_label(form.ime, 'Ime')
```

it rendered the translation for key `Ime`. Same thing happend to email field. Everything else is in order. I just changed the label value to 'Search for name' or something like that.

As to how to limit translations to only one form, I don't know. I read Translations section but couldn't find anything.